# How to resize images in a slideshow for a Responsive Theme?

Tags: 7, theming

I am using a responsive theme in which I have a slideshow on the homepage of the slide. I am creating the Slideshow as a Block using Views.

Question: How do I make the slideshow (i.e. the images) re-sizable as the screen size is changed?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Flex Slider](https://drupal.org/project/flexslider) either alone, or in combination with [FlexSlider Views Slideshow](https://drupal.org/project/flexslider_views_slideshow) (which provides integration with Views Slideshow in case you already use that one).

Flex Slider module integrates the Flex Slider library with Drupal and allows you to build responsive and resizable slideshows. You'll find plenty of documentation on the project page to fit it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below CSS

```
.views-slideshow-cycle-main-frame {
  width: 100% !important;
}
.views-slideshow-cycle-main-frame-row {
  position: relative !important;
}
```

Or visit [this](http://burofriesen.nl/en/creating-responsive-views-slideshow-drupal-7-text-overlay) page to know more.

Comment: There is a saying **Don't misuse !important** `width` and `maxwidth` might be an option, but it doesn't have to be wrapped with unnecessary `!default` or `!important`

Comment: @JhilkeDai: Media query can deal with the !important. If not CSS hierarchy will take care of that.